# In Windows 10, is it possible to run 2 instances of an app and have each audio stream sent to a different output?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, gaming, speakers

I know that Windows 10 has a setting where people can select which audio output device is used for which app. I'm wondering if it's possible to run 2 instances of the same app (for example, a video game) and have each instance output its audio to a different source. Specifically, the scenario I'm dealing with is that I'm trying to run a game on my PC, with 2 Xbox controllers connected, and each player has their own sound for the game.

While running both instances, if I go into Sound Settings -> App volume and devices preferences, then scroll through the list, I did indeed see an entry for each instance of the game that's currently running. However, changing the audio output for one of them affects both.

Answer (score 0):

I did some looking at applications where I might or do run multiple instances and the overall settings are the same. So in numerous cases you cannot set individual settings and it appears your app is one of these.